# How can I accept user input from an NSTextField to instantiate a new object using the stringValue as the variable name?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

For example, I have a class "Person", with all its member variables.

I have a UI with an **NSTextField** and a **Submit** button. When the user enters a name in the text field and clicks submit, a new "person" object is instantiated, so that

```
let (NSTextField.stringValue) = Person(name: NSTextField.stringValue)
```

The idea is to have these "Person" objects stored in an array of objects for later reference and modification.

Alternatively, I have considered of course that each Person object has a string variable "Name", so that creating a new object with the name of another existing object doesn't overwrite anything currently instantiated--but in that case, I need a way to iterate generic names like person1, person2, person3. I'm unable to find anything about how to automate that process either, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you start to think "I need to somehow dynamically create new variables", don't. You probably don't need to do that. Most of the times, you need a kind of *data structure*.

Here, you want variables with custom names. You should probably use a dictionary. A dictionary is like a real dictionary, you have keys and values. Each key correspond to a value and keys cannot contain duplicates.

A dictionary with `String` as keys and `Person` as values should do the job:

```
var myDictionary = [String: Person]()
```

Now, instead of doing this:

```
let (NSTextField.stringValue) = Person(name: NSTextField.stringValue)
```

you do

```
myDictionary[NSTextField.stringValue] = Person(name: NSTextField.stringValue)
```

To access a person, do this:

```
myDictionary["Tom"]
```

For more info, see the "Dictionaries" section of this; https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: Ah! I had it backwards.

Comment: @BrianMagus if you think my answer answers your questi, please consider accepting it!